# grafana display a text/string value from an API

Tags: grafana

How do you display a text/string value in Grafana with the data fetched from the [JSON API plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/)?

My datasource the url is https://bensapi.pythonanywhere.com/ that returns:

```
{"message":"Hello from Flask!","status":"success"}
```

Setting up the data source for this URL and EXPLORE option it works, the string on the bottom is what I am looking to display:

[image]

In grafana selecting this type of chart:

[image]

And trying to recreate my steps from the EXPLORE process of the data source I cant seem to plot the `Hello from Flask` string on a dashboard. Any tips appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the doc of [JSON API plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/):

https://marcus.se.net/grafana-json-datasource/troubleshooting#why-do-i-get-unable-to-graph-data-when-i-try-to-graph-the-query-results

> The Graph and Time series panels can only display time series. To create a query that returns time series, make sure that it contains at least two fields:
>
> A Time field that contains the timestamps for the X-axis
> A Number field that contains the values for the Y-axis

So your API response (simple `string`) can't be graphed.

Comment: would I just seek a certain dashboard that handle strings? Or is this something that isnt designed for grafana?

Comment: any best practices appreciated. I could probably fumble through a custom react plugin, is that something worth while?

Comment: @bbartling Keep in mind terminology: Grafana dashboard has panel(s). You are looking for a panel (not a dashboard), which works with strings. That is for example table panel (that's used in the explore mode - see "table" there). So select more suitable panel type for your data or make more suitable data for selected panel type.

Answer (score 5):

While [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179677/1366871) is correct for the graph and time series panel, you stated that you are using the stat panel.

There you can set what type of values are shown: In the panel settings go to `Value options` -> `Fields`. There the default is `Numeric Fields`. So when you haven't changed that, it is the reason 'No data' is shown for your string. Set it to `All Fields` to make the panel show strings.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up using with [the JSON API](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/) is the [TABLE panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/table/) to display text values from a JSON API PAYLOAD. Looks like this below, the API JSON PATH to represent the data into columns:

[image]